# Downloadable File from Django Management Command

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views, django-management-command

I have been researching for days, and I still cant figure this out! Hopefully a fellow StackOverflower can help me out here.

So, right now I have a custom django management command that runs a report and sends and email containing the report as an xlsx file (excel). Now im wondering if there is a way to get that excel report on a website so that people could download it and view it for themselves if they dont want to get an email.

I already have my urls and html templates set up, all I need now is to put a link to my report (that is generated from my management command) into my template on my website so that anyone could download it!!! Please help! Im stuck!

**management command** (condensed)

```
FILENAME = tempfile.mkstemp('.xlsx', 'EDIComplianceReport')
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

    final_results[carrier_scac] = carrier_results


    ts_util.sendMessage(['cmeeks@re-trans.com'],
                        'EDI Compliance Report', '\n EDI Compliance Report Attached',
                        self.populateSpreadsheet(final_results))



    def populateSpreadsheet(self, results):
            workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(STATICFILES_DIRS + 'ediportal/ComplianceSummaryReports/' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))) #appends a unique time at the end of the file to prevent overwrite



            format01 = workbook.add_format({'border': 1, 'bold': True,'align': 'center', 'bg_color': '#DDDDDD'})
            format02 = workbook.add_format({'border': 1, 'bold': True, 'bg_color': '#9999FF', 'align': 'center'})
            format03 = workbook.add_format({'border': 1, 'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red', 'bg_color': 'white', 'align': 'center'})
            format04 = workbook.add_format({'border': 1, 'bold': True, 'bg_color': 'white', 'align': 'center'})

            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Summary")
            row = 0
            col = 0
            sorted_carriers = list(CARRIERS.keys())
            sorted_carriers.sort()
            for i, carrier in enumerate(sorted_carriers):
                worksheet.write(i+row, 0, carrier, format01)
                worksheet.write(i+row, 1, 'Estimated Overall Compliance', format01)
                worksheet.write(i+row+1, 1, results[carrier]['overall_compliance'], format03)
                for ind, code in enumerate(CARRIERS[carrier].split(',')):
                    if code != 'overall_compliance':
                        worksheet.write(i+row, ind+2, code, format02)
                        worksheet.write(i+row+1, ind+2, results[carrier][code], format04)
                row += 2

            workbook.close()
            return FILENAME[1]
```

Thus, I want to serve the file called EDIComplianceReport.xslx and allow others to download it as a link on a html template.

**Right now it is just running on my local host machine!!!**
Ive had an idea of saving the excel workbooks to a static folder and grabbing it from there, but i just cant figure out the exact code to embed the document in my template...

Comment: What is the error that you observed on server? Check error_logs of apache. Are you having some kinda permission issue?

Comment: Its not that I'm getting any type of error. Its just that I cant figure out how to implement a downloadable file on my website in the first place!

Comment: You can use media_root and media_url to setup download directory.

Comment: okay, how would i do that specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Set your `MEDIA_ROOT` in settings.py . You can try `MEDIA_ROOT=BASE_DIR+'/media'`. After that create your media url in settings.py as `MEDIA_URL='/media/'`. Then in template you can mention download url as `src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/<DATE STRING HERE>"` [check Django docs on media files here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/files/) and static files [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/). It is better to setup a model in your app's models.py to handle file uploads. A typical model looks like below.

```
class ExcelUploads(models.Model):
    excel_file = models.FileField(upload_to='/media/excel_files')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.description
```

To provide download links for your excel files, make use of `{% static %} template tag` or `{{MEDIA_URL}}` after adding `django.template.context_processors.media to your 'context_processors' under TEMPLATES section of settings.py`.static tags are usually used to serve static files like css, js etc. Its good to use media_url to serve file downloads.

So based on the model definitions in the answer posted, your download links looks like `src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{ExcelUploads[0].excel_file.url}}"`